# Replacing the 'reset' button with a normal star when using RateIt for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Using [rateit](http://rateit.codeplex.com/documentation), a plugin for jQuery, to replace a `select` element with stars.

The problem is that the reset button takes the place of the first star and when the `resetable` variable is set to `false`, the first select option simply isn't available, but when it is `true`, the hover & selected effects don't work as a user will expect.

I have tried changing the image of the reset button but it behaves incorrectly.

[Here is is with resetable set to false](http://jsfiddle.net/ru2wh/2/). The first star is gone, and my minimum selection value is 2

[Here it is with resetable set to true](http://jsfiddle.net/gP8BR/), see how the first star hover/selected effect doesn't work as expected, but I can get my first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Rateit plugin to progressively enhance a select list you need to include a option for 0 i.e. no stars. Do this and everything starts to work nicely.

http://jsfiddle.net/ru2wh/7/